# Radio Button with Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, radio-button, actionlistener

This program is supposed to allow the user "design" a house by picking from three groups of radio buttons and display the up-to-date (refreshes every time a change is made) total cost of the house in the same window but I can't seem to get the cost to actually display anything but $0.0 or null and I am pretty sure the problem is with the way I am using my action listener. Any help on how to fix this would be very appreciated.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jmynewhome;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/**
 *
 * @author Peter
 */
public class JMyNewHome extends JFrame{
private JPanel panel;
private double cost1;
private double cost2;
private double cost3;
private JLabel messageLabel;
private JRadioButton aspen;
private JRadioButton brittany;
private JRadioButton colonial;
private JRadioButton dartmoor;
private ButtonGroup house;
private JRadioButton bedroom2;
private JRadioButton bedroom3;
private JRadioButton bedroom4;
private ButtonGroup bedroom;
private JRadioButton noGarage;
private JRadioButton garage1;
private JRadioButton garage2;
private JRadioButton garage3;
private ButtonGroup garage;
private String total;

    public JMyNewHome() {
        setTitle("My new home");
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      messageLabel = new JLabel("$"+ total);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);

    }


    private void buildPanel()
    {


        aspen = new JRadioButton("Aspen");
        brittany = new JRadioButton("Brittany", true);
        colonial = new JRadioButton("Colonial");
        dartmoor = new JRadioButton("Dartmoor");
        bedroom2 = new JRadioButton("2 bedrooms", true);
        bedroom3 = new JRadioButton("3 bedrooms");
        bedroom4 = new JRadioButton("4 bedrooms");
        noGarage = new JRadioButton("No garage");
        garage1 = new JRadioButton("1 car garage");
        garage2 = new JRadioButton("2 car garage");
        garage3 = new JRadioButton("3 car garage");

        house = new ButtonGroup();
        bedroom = new ButtonGroup();
        garage = new ButtonGroup();

        house.add(aspen);
        house.add(brittany);
        house.add(colonial);
        house.add(dartmoor);

        bedroom.add(bedroom2);
        bedroom.add(bedroom3);
        bedroom.add(bedroom4);

        garage.add(noGarage);
        garage.add(garage1);
        garage.add(garage2);
        garage.add(garage3);     

        aspen.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        brittany.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        colonial.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        dartmoor.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        bedroom2.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        bedroom3.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        bedroom4.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        noGarage.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        garage1.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        garage2.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        garage3.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(aspen);
        panel.add(brittany);
        panel.add(colonial);
        panel.add(dartmoor);
        panel.add(bedroom2);
        panel.add(bedroom3);
        panel.add(bedroom4);
        panel.add(noGarage);
        panel.add(garage1);
        panel.add(garage2);
        panel.add(garage3);
        panel.add(messageLabel);


    }
    private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            total = "";
           cost1 = 0.0;
           cost2 = 0.0;
           cost3 = 0.0;
            if (e.getSource() == aspen)
                cost1 = 100000;

            else if(e.getSource() == brittany)
                cost1 = 120000;



            else if(e.getSource() == colonial)
                cost1 = 180000;

            else if(e.getSource() == dartmoor)
                cost1 = 250000;

            if (e.getSource() == bedroom2)
                cost2 = 10500 * 2;

            else if(e.getSource() == bedroom3)
                cost2 = 10500 * 3;

            else if(e.getSource() == bedroom4)
                cost2 = 10500 * 4;

            if(e.getSource() == noGarage)
                cost3 = 0;

            else if(e.getSource() == garage1)
                cost3 = 7775;

            else if(e.getSource() == garage2)
                cost3 = 7775 * 2;

            else if(e.getSource() == garage3)
                cost3 = 7775 * 3;


            total = Double.toString(cost1 + cost2 + cost3);
        }
    }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
       new JMyNewHome();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
messageLabel.setText(total);
```

At the end of your `actioPerformed()`

You've changed the `total` in the `actioPerformed()` but you never set that total to the label

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    ...
    ...

    total = Double.toString(cost1 + cost2 + cost3);

    messageLabel.setText("$" + total);
}
```

**Edit:**
With the code below, you're resetting total

```
total = Double.toString(cost1 + cost2 + cost3);
```

You want this

```
total += Double.toString(cost1 + cost2 + cost3);
```

Comment: Ah thanks that is it. I still have the problem of the cost of each part not adding with the others, as in the cost show is only the cost associated with the most recent radio button selected.

Comment: See my edit. Simple fix. Please accept answer if this answer helped solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. sorry I did not accept the answer at first. it is my first time using this website I wasn't fully aware of the proper etiquette.